# ODR violation with template specializations

Tags: c++, c++11, one-definition-rule

We have a header file which contains some residuals for various floating point precisions:

```
template <typename T>
struct rsdTarget {
  static const double value;
};

template <>
const double rsdTarget<half>::value = (double)(1.0e-3);

template <>
const double rsdTarget<float>::value = (double)(1.0e-7);

template <>
const double rsdTarget<double>::value = (double)(1.0e-12);
```

This has worked because this header had only been included in a single compilation unit. Now I try to use this header in multiple compilation units and I get linker errors stemming from the ODR:

```
CMakeFiles/tests_g.dir/random_gauge.cc.o:(.rodata+0x108): multiple definition of `rsdTarget<double>::value'
CMakeFiles/tests_g.dir/clover_product.cc.o:(.rodata+0x548): first defined here
```

The initialization probably needs to go into a source file and be taken out of the header file. However it seems to be prohibited to but an `extern` in front of the `const double`.

What would I have to do such that this works with multiple compilation units?

## Update

I thought that solving this for `double` would fix it fully. However, there is a second non-literal type which I also have to carry through:

```
template <typename T>
struct tolerance {
  static const QDP::Double small; // Always fail
};

template <>
const QDP::Double tolerance<half>::small = QDP::Double(5.0e-3);

template <>
const QDP::Double tolerance<float>::small = QDP::Double(1.0e-6);

template <>
const QDP::Double tolerance<double>::small = QDP::Double(1.0e-7);
```

I cannot seem to use that with `constexpr` because that type does not support it (`constexpr` ctor needed, right?). Which of the solutions works with this as well?

Comment: Use `inline` on the specialization.  (And consider replacing this with an inline variable if you are using up to date compiler)

Comment: You can also use `__declspec(selectany)` before template specialization for Microsoft compiler.

Comment: Inline variables seem to need C++17, we are only up to C++11 now. It is a high-performance code which needs to run on various HPC systems with unpredictable compiler versions. I'll try to fiddle around with inline.

Comment: @ikleschenkov: I don't see us ever using the Microsoft compiler. We use GCC, Clang, IBM XLC (though not for this code), Intel C++ and Cray Compiler. Our target systems run on Linux :-).

Comment: I have updated the questions because the problem turned out to be nastier than I thought. Sorry about that!

Comment: VTT's solution should work with user defined types, even if they aren't constexpr constructable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow all these definitions reside in the header file without causing linker errors when it is used in multiple translation units, you just need to turn them into templates as well:

```
template<typename T, typename TDummy = void>
struct rsdTarget;

template<typename TDummy>
struct rsdTarget<half, TDummy>
{
    static const double value;
};

template<typename TDummy>
const double rsdTarget<half, TDummy>::value = (double)(1.0e-3);

template<typename TDummy>
struct rsdTarget<float, TDummy>
{
    static const double value;
};

template<typename TDummy>
const double rsdTarget<float, TDummy>::value = (double)(1.0e-7);

template<typename TDummy>
struct rsdTarget<double, TDummy>
{
    static const double value;
};

template<typename TDummy>
const double rsdTarget<double, TDummy>::value = (double)(1.0e-12);
```